# Automatic Content Sanitization in Sharepoint 2010/2013

Tags: workflow, document-library, content, content-approval, approval-process

Is it possible to perform basic document sanitization tasks in Sharepoint 2010 or 2013? 
I would like to be able to trigger the sanitization task based on a set of user defined rule. Examples of content I would like to remove are references to customer names/contract values for documents in the library. I do not want redaction. For example, I want all specific customer names to be replaced with generic names such as (customer) and all numeric values representing contract amounts with a generic text such as (contract amount).

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with custom code in an [event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but it will likely to difficult to get it exactly right. For example how would the program determine a contract amount from any other amount?
Even then you will want someone manually reviewing (at least some of) the documents to make sure the program did not miss anything.
In the long run, unless you have a ton of documents to go through you are better off setting up a workflow that assigns someone a task to review each document that gets added (and maybe changed).